# Highlight specific rows in datadridview c# according to some

Tags: c#

i'm working on a desktop application in visual studio. i want my datagridview to highlight the rows where the values of some cells is not within a certain range. for example if i enter a value to a column X of the row and the value is not between 5 and 8 i want the row to appear in another color red for example.

please anyone have an idea how to do it??

Comment: i tried these but its not working dont know why, i have a table of results with 4 columns one of them is 'PH' , i want my gridview to highlight all the lines of the tables where PH is between 5 and 8 . can you please help me im a beginner in c# i dont know much about it thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know vb.net so the syntax is going to be a little different but it will look something like this

```
            For i As Integer = 0 To datagrid.Attributes.Count - 1

                If somecondtion Then
                    datagrid.Columns.Item(i).CellStyle.BackColor = Color.somecolor
                Else
                    datagrid.Columns.Item(i).CellStyle.BackColor = Color.othercolor
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;

        int CellValue;
        if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString(),out CellValue))
        {
            if (CellValue < 5 && CellValue > 8)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { ForeColor = Color.Red };
            }


        }
```

Use the event to look which cell changed, and manipulate the layout via CellSytle class.